# How to generate a mask out of grayscale X-Ray images?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, deep-learning

I have been working on my master's thesis recently, which is a deep learning algorithm to detect objects positions in X-Ray images. I am following a segmentation approach using deep convolutional network (UNET) to train it for such a detection. Unfortunately, the data I have for this purpose does not include the ground truth masks, and it only contains the coordinates of the starting and end points of the bounding box/es where the object/s is/are. Kindly find an example of the data:

[image]

and the Bounding box:

[image].

For this image attached above, the ground truth data included is as follow: [618, 248, 770, 6, 1, 0, 0] which indicate the X and Y coordinates of the starting point of the bounding box, the X and Y coordinates of the end point, the object label, and the rest are not much of an importance.

To generate the masks, I have tried several approaches like: Otsu Thresholding, Edge detection, etc. But none of these techniques gave a satisfying quality for the masks. My supervisors recommended that I should simply draw lines that determine the position and orientation of the object, which I did Kindly find it here:

[image]

but I am looking for a way of generating better masks since we will also need to detect the tips of the wires, which cannot be detected using straight lines, and nevertheless, The objects are not all linear, some of them have curves.

How can I generate better binary masks that include only the object? Any hint is more than welcome.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You only need to perform Otsu Threshold on the region within the mask and superimpose the result

Comment: Will the objects of interest always be in black?

Comment: @JeruLuke Thank you for the comment! I tried applying the Otsu thresholding approach to the bounding box region, but the result is still kind of noisy! and yes, all objects appear in black on the images i have. Any other ideas for tackling this problem here? :(

Comment: If the objects will always be black, then you can set a threshold and binarize the ROI. Later superimpose it on a black screen